# Always On VPN Bug or what

Tags: vpn, direct-access

I configure Always On VPN with this guide: https://directaccess.richardhicks.com/2017/12/11/always-on-vpn-windows-10-device-tunnel-step-by-step-configuration-using-powershell/

Stuck at verifying creation of the VPN device tunnel. Everything in elevated powershell prompt goes well and ends just like as it should: "Created DeviceTunnel profile. Complete" But when i try to check it via Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection or Get-VpnConnection, I don't see created device tunnel. (powershell from system and powershell from admin) I am using default microsoft script provided in guide, no changes have been made. (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/vpn/vpn-device-tunnel-config#deployment-and-testing)

I'm struggling with it for days, please help.

Windows 10 20H2 Enterprise.

Comment: Take example scripts of AOVPN_Device_Tunnel_script_example.txt, change the file extension from .txt to .ps1 and modify the XML parameters as per your configuration. Then run the script with PowerShell ISE. Then check it via Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection. For how to create the VPN template for client devices, you can refer to the following article:http://blog.tofte-it.dk/tutorial-deploy-always-on-vpn/

Comment: @Candy Thanks alot, that guide helped ! :)

Comment: You are welcome. :)